# Creating a spreadsheet from a text file

Tags: text-processing

I am writing a shell script which takes a text file as input and generate a spreadsheet as output. I have single text file similar to the one shown below.

```
Name:John
Age:30
Gender:male
Name:Bob
Age:65
Gender:Male
```

and the pattern goes on repeating several times. I have to create a spreadsheet with name, age and gender as fields as shown below.

```
Name Age Gender
John 30  Male
Bob  65  Male
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a tab delimited text file ready to import into excel:

```
printf "Name\tAge\tGender\n" > outfile
cut -d: -f2- <infile | paste - - - >> outfile
```

- `printf` creates the tab delimited header
- `cut` from the second field to end of line
- `paste` formats the output into three columns which are tab delimited and amends the outfile

You could also group the commands and redirect only once:

```
{
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' Name Age Gender
cut -d: -f2- <infile | paste - - -
} > outfile
```

Comment: @fdo your code is working fine with fixed rows. I realized this later that the number of rows in my text are always varying. Basically I am using xidel command to extract text from html page. If html page changes, text changes and so does the number of rows. So I have to match the field 1 with the header first, if match is found then insert field 2 in the spreadsheet under that header. I have been trying to do this but couldn't code it by now.

Answer (score 0):

Well the following works if the file always has three lines for each record.

```
echo "Name Age Gender" >>OUTPUT.txt; xargs -n 3 < INPUTFILE.txt |sed 's/Name:\|Age:\|Gender://g' >> OUTPUT.txt
```

I'm certain there are more eloquent ways of handling this.

Comment: @don_crissti yes man the output is distorted if there is a space between field values as you illustrated above. Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: @SwateshPakhare why don't you use another character as the delimiter? e.g  '|' or ','?